# How to show <tr> tag on clicking button and prevent page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Requirement is to hide a  tag initially, if user clicks forwardbutton without checking any radio or checkbutton we have show the  tag and have to prevent page refresh. But it is permanently not submitting on click, Plese someone help me.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var y=$('input').filter(':checked').length;
alert(y);
if(y == 0 )
{
   $('#Q1_7_label').parents('TR').hide();       
}
$('#forwardbutton').live('click',function(event)
 {
    var x=$('input').filter(':checked').length;
    if(x==0)
     {
      $('#Q1_7_label').parents('TR').show(); 
      return false;
     }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#forwardbutton').live('click',function(event)
 {
    var x=$('input').filter(':checked').length;
    if(x==0)
     {
      $('#Q1_7_label').parents('TR').show(); 
      return false;
     }
     return true;
 });
```

Just add `return true` at the end of the function

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
return false;
```

with

```
event.preventDefault();
```